# Can an OpenAL device be queried about what frequency and format it prefers?

Tags: c++, c, audio, openal

From [The OpenAL Programmers Guide](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Documentation/OpenAL_Programmers_Guide.pdf):

```
void alBufferData(
    ALuint buffer,
    ALenum format,
    const ALvoid *data,
    ALsizei size,
    ALsizei freq
```

);

Can an OpenAL device be queried about what frequency and format it prefers to use without needing to resample the buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik you can get only frequency, not the format. When you create function using `alcCreateContext` you specify attributes for mixing buffer. If you pass there `NULL` then you can query these attributes later using `alcGetIntegerv`:

1. First query attribute count using `ALC_ATTRIBUTES_SIZE` enum
2. Then allocate large enough buffer and query attributes using `ALC_ALL_ATTRIBUTES` enum
3. Buffer will contain pairs of attribute names and its values: [attrib1, value1, attrib2, value2, ...]
4. Frequency enum name is `ALC_FREQUENCY` - loop through array and search for this enum.

As for format - use signed short for stereo or mono sounds. This should give good enough performance on all platforms (even those who use floats for mixing, converting short to short to float is fast operation).